# How to translate a postgresql search query to use criteriaBuilder

Tags: postgresql, spring-boot, hibernate, spring-data-jpa, full-text-search

I want to take this query using full text search in postgresql and be able to write it in spring boot using the CriteriaBuilder but without the native query using jpa functions

"SELECT * FROM ideas WHERE to_tsvector(name || description) @@ to_tsquery('dark')"

Please help if you can

Answer (score 0):

You can create a custom Hibernate function and then use that e.g. `cb.equal(cb.function("my_search", Boolean.class, root.get("name"), root.get("description"), cb.literal("dark")), true)`.

```
public class MySearch implements SQLFunction {

    @Override
    public boolean hasArguments() {
        return true;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean hasParenthesesIfNoArguments() {
        return true;
    }

    @Override
    public Type getReturnType(Type firstArgumentType, Mapping mapping) throws QueryException {
        return StandardBasicTypes.BOOLEAN;
    }

    @Override
    public String render(Type firstArgumentType, List args, SessionFactoryImplementor factory) throws QueryException {
        String searchArgs = "";
        for (int i = 0; i < args.size() - 1; i++) {
            if (i != 0) {
                searchArgs += " || ";
            }
            searchArgs += args.get(i);
        }
        String query = args.get(args.size() - 1);
        return "to_tsvector(" + searchArgs + ") @@ to_tsquery(" + query + ")";
    }
}
```